# Como obter valor do DB para uma variável?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Tenho a seguinte dúvida:
Tenho um banco de dados no mongoDB, faço a busca dos dados pelo NodeJS ele me retorna tudo certo, porém gostaria de jogar esse valor da busca para uma variável, para fazer uma comparação. Tipo busco a data no DB e gostaria de comparar essa data com a data atual do sistema.

```
const CRUD = {
retrieve:function(query,mod){
    //console.log("Query",query);                   
    Model.findOne(query,mod, function(err,data){
        if(err) return console.log('ERRO: ',err);
        return console.log('Dado',data);                            
    });
};
```

Depois chamo esse CRUD em outro arquivo. Há uma forma de pegar o resultado dessa busca e jogar em uma variável para comparar com outra ? tipo assim:

```
var query3  = {data:'2016-12-04'};
var fields  = {data:1,_id:0};
CRUD.retrieve(query3,fields);
```

O resultado do CRUD é esse : Dado {data:'2016-12-04'}

Answer (score 1):

Devias criar um novo argumento para esse método, para teres uma callback que seja corrida quando o resultado estiver disponivel.

```
const CRUD = {
    retrieve: function(query, mod, done){
        Model.findOne(query, mod, done);
    }
};
```

e depois chamares com esse argumento:

```
var query3  = {data:'2016-12-04'};
var fields  = {data:1, _id:0};
CRUD.retrieve(query3, fields, function(err, data) {
    if (err) return console.log('ERRO: ', err);
    // a partir daqui podes usar a variável "data"
    // e comparar o seu valor com outras variáveis
    console.log('Dado', data == 'algo a comparar');
});
```